# sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5 : I fired this command and the boot sector of my drive got corrupted?

Tags: dual-boot, mount, data-recovery

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5
```

I fired this command and the boot sector of my drive got corrupted ! I was attempting to open the NTFS partition using Ubuntu.
It gave mount error so I tried the above command and now the boot sector of that drive is corrupted !
How can i restore the data in the drive , I have lot of important data in it.

Comment: `ntfsfix` has nothing to do with the boot-sector. How you know your boot-sector is corrupted. Gather more information about your system. Create and then boot  to Ubuntu-installer choose `Try Ubuntu` run `sudo fdisk -l` and paste output to your question.

Comment: @mook765 it has nothing to do with the MBR but it has a lot to do with the PBR (the partition boot sector) which is the first sector of `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: @mook765 after firing the ntfsfix command , the terminal gave an output where it displayed "rewriting your boot sector" and thus i know the boot sector is corrupted ! Also the sda5 partition is not getting mounted !

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Exactly ! , i can boot both win8.1 and ubuntu but the sda5 partition is damaged

Comment: Anyways, `ntfsfix` does write only the dirty bit, nothing serious. It does not corrupt stuff. To repair a slightly broken NTFS drive, as usual, you should use Windows. If it doesn't mount after that command, it was not mounting before as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create a boot able USB of Ubuntu image.
Then boot into live USB install boot-repair and run boot-repair as a root user. After that select recommended repairs.
If this doesn't work then try to install test drive (bootsectorfix).

Boot-repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Test-drive:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

Comment: will it work on windows partition , as the partition i've mentioned is not windows installed partition but an another internal partiton..

Comment: It will work. Give it a try !!!